# Algorithms behind Gridster/Masonry/Gridstack

Tags: javascript, grid, masonry, gridster

Do you know what algorithms are behind gridster/masonry/gridstack?

Concrete example : http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/demo/float.html

You can place DIVs anywhere on the grid and the grid is extended dynamically. Also there are collisions, the positions are fixed and the DIVs are resizable and they snap to a specific cell width/height.
How is that done?

Comment: At least gridster and gridstack are open source. Gridstack is pretty small and simple library.

Comment: Yes I have seen that, but I think the code is really difficult to understand. For example the variable names are not always meaningful. Where would you start when writing such a library? I would like to understand the basic concept between these libraries, how they work.

Comment: I'm author of gridstack.js so I can say about it. There are two classes there: GridstackEngine which is responded for internal representation of the grid (movements, collisions, packing, etc) and GridStack which is bridge between UI and GridstackEngine. 

So you can start from GridStackEngine it's pretty simple.

Comment: @PavelReznikov, dude, are you still maintaining GridStack frequently? or are you planning to ? I am in the middle of making decision on whether use your stuff or not

Comment: @KevinSimple I'm biased, but you should use it. There was a brief period where it wasn't updated, but it's getting a lot of attention now.

Comment: @PavelReznikov - Is gridstack compatiable with Backbone.js ?